# How to make Cassandra fast

Tags: cassandra

I installed the Cassandra 2.0.0 on RedHat Linux using YUM. It's single node with the default setting. the Linux has 4 cores and 8G RAM. When I ran the following write/read single column family testing. the produced result seems pretty slow. Please advice how to make it fast. 
thanks.

Each row has 100 columns.

**Cassandra Write**

```
Row Byte    Time (ms)           
2   110K    17          
30  162K    170         
100 540K    562         
500 2700K   2459            
1000    5408K   5570            
2000    10797K  8707            
4000    21583K  3975            
9000    17799K  10600
```

Cassandra Read** 
It took 6.5 second to read 9000 rows from a single column family.

Comment: Cassandra scales linearly with horizontal scaling. Throw another machine in to (hopefully) double the performance.

Comment: What performance are you expecting? What is your column family model? What other processes are running on this server that could potentially hamper performance? Also, Cassandra is a BigTable data store: you need at least 2-4 nodes in your cluster to make a credible performance estimate. Is it possible to setup another node?

Comment: I am expecting the write and read time less than 1 second. The less the merrier. My column family is at the row based with each row having   150+ columns. thank you all for your quick responses. I'm trying to set up another node and will let you know the numbers.

Comment: I added another Cassandra node. It's total two nodes now. I tried the 30 rows with around 162K byte data, it took 244 MS. It's even more than previous 170 MS. Any suggestions? thank you.

Comment: No one is pointing fingers at this, but how are you actually writing data? If you use **prepared** batch statements from the Datastax driver that will help eliminate speed loss due to a bad driver.

Comment: Good question. I used "Easy Cassandra" with Spring Data to annotate the Bean with @ Id and @ Column. The Cassandra nodes have no load. As I only use them to do POC. I will try the way you suggested. Only that I have a hundred plus columns. Will that be an viable solution?

Comment: @CandySmurf 100+ columns is perfectly fine. Honestly, cassandra can take much more than that. Another thought: the [pycassa](http://pycassa.github.io/pycassa/tutorial.html) python client is great for rapidly developing read/write test scripts.

Comment: Also, giving us the schema of your column family + the queries you are trying to run, will help us understand your read performance.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil. I have two Cassandra nodes with one column family. it's a simple table with 100+ columns. Each row has one row key. It's similar to a simple DB table with one primary key. My current experience is the data volume matters. If I decrease the columns to two columns, it's faster. If I increase the columns back to 100+, it's much slower. This seems not the behavior Cassandra should have.

Comment: Do you think both nodes are on the SAN drive matter?

Comment: @CandySmurf its been 2 years since you asked this question with no real answer. did you finally resolved your issues?