# Correcting improper usage of Cassandra

Tags: performance, cassandra, distributed, cassandra-2.0

I have a similar question that was unanswered (but had many comments):

[How to make Cassandra fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173130/how-to-make-cassandra-fast)

My setup:
Ubuntu Server
AWS service - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz, 4GB Ram.
2 Nodes of Cassandra Datastax Community Edition: (2.1.3).
PHP 5.5.9. With datastax php-driver

I come from a MySQL database knowledge with very basic NoSQL hands on in terms of ElasticSearch (now called Elastic) and MongoDB in terms of Documents storage.

When I read how to use Cassandra, here are the bullets that I understood

- It is distributed
- You can have replicated rings to distribute data
- You need to establish partition keys for maximum efficiency
- Rethink your query rather than to use indices
- Model according to queries and not data
- Deletes are bad
- You can only sort starting from the second key of your primary key set
- Cassandra has "fast" write

I have a PHP Silex framework API that receive a batch json data and is inserted into 4 tables as a minimum, 6 at maximum (mainly due to different types of sort that I need).

At first I only had two nodes of Cassandra. I ran Apache Bench to test. Then I added a third node, and it barely shaved off a fraction of a second at higher batch size concurrency.

```
Concurrency Batch size  avg. time (ms) - 2 Nodes avg. time (ms) - 3 Nodes
1                 5                   288              180
1                 50                  421              302
1                 400                 1 298            1 504
25                5                   1 993            2 111
25                50                  3 636            3 466
25                400                 32 208           21 032
100               5                   5 115            5 167
100               50                  11 776           10 675
100               400                 61 892           60 454
```

A batch size is the number of entries (to the 4-6 tables) it is making per call.
So batch of 5, means it is making 5x (4-6) table insert worth of data. At higher batch size / concurrency the application times out.

There are 5 columns in a table with relatively small size of data (mostly int with text being no more than approx 10 char long)

My keyspace is the following:

```
 user_data | True | org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy | {"replication_factor":"1"}
```

My "main" question is: what did I do wrong? It seems to be this is relatively small data set of that considering that Cassandra was built on BigDataTable at very high write speed.

- Do I add more nodes beyond 3 in order to speed up?
- Do I change my replication factor and do Quorum / Read / Write and then hunt for a sweet spot from the datastax doc: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html
- Do I switch framework, go node.js for higher concurrency for example.
- Do I rework my tables, as I have no good example as to how effectively use column family? I need some hint for this one.

For the table question:
I'm tracking history of a user. User has an event and is associated to a media id, and there so extra meta data too.
So columns are: event_type, user_id, time, media_id, extra_data.
I need to sort them differently therefore I made different tables for them (as I understood how Cassandra data modeling should work...I am perhaps wrong). Therefore I'm replicating the different data across various tables.

Help?

**EDIT PART HERE**

the application also has redis and mysql attached for other CRUD points of interest such as retrieving a user data and caching it for faster pull.
so far on avg with MySQL and then Redis activated, I have a 72ms after Redis kicks in, 180ms on MySQL pre-redis.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is you're trying to benchmark the whole system, without knowing what any individual component can do. Are you trying to see how fast an individual operation is? or how many operations per second you can do? They're different values.

I typically recommend you start by benchmarking Cassandra. Modern Cassandra can typically do 20-120k operations per second per server. With RF=3, that means somewhere between 5k and 40k reads / second or writes/second. Use cassandra-stress to make sure cassandra is doing what you expect, THEN try to loop in your application and see if it matches. If you slow way down, then you know the application is your bottleneck, and you can start thinking about various improvements (different driver, different language, async requests instead of sync, etc).

Right now, you're doing too much and analyzing too little. Break the problem into smaller pieces. Solve the individual pieces, then put the puzzle together.

Edit: Cassandra 2.1.3 is getting pretty old. It has some serious bugs. Use 2.1.11 or 2.2.3. If you're just starting development, 2.2.3 may be OK (and let's assume you'll actually go to production with 2.2.5 or so). If you're ready to go prod tomorrow, use 2.1.x instead.

Comment: Thank you for responding and giving me some insight. I have added some app benchmark of the application's benchmark so far without the cassandra inside. My next step is to take your recommendation of using cassandra-stress. Can you add to your answer the following: what command should I start off with to stress it. I have already switch drivers from a vendor package because the driver offers async instead of sync and datastax recommended to use async instead of large batch. what is your opinion on that. please add it to your response. thank you.